# Alpine Linux: How-To enforce user to change the password on next login?

Tags: passwords, alpine-linux

Is it possible to enforce that a user have to change the password after the next login in Alpine Linux?

**Background**:
We deploy a bunch of Alpine Linux VMs for IaaS. We use packer for that. During the configuration all machines gets the same password (from the script).

Links for other Linux distributions
[tecmint.com](https://www.tecmint.com/force-user-to-change-password-next-login-in-linux/)
[cybercity.biz](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-force-users-to-change-passwords/)

I have tried `chage -d 0 {user-name}` here is the result that alpine do not know the command. The package manager (apk add), was not able to find the package.

Also I tried `passwd --expire {user-name}`. passwd is a valid command but the option -e or --expire is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chage` is part of the `shadow` package, so installing this package should work for you:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=chage&path=&name=&branch=edge&repo=community&arch=x86_64

Comment: It works! 

``` 
apk add shadow
chage -d 0 {user-name}
{ENTER CURRENT PASSWORD of user}
reboot
{Login with current Password and set the new one}
```